# EF6 Stored Procedure does not accept parameters

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

I am using EF6 and I need to execute stored procedure. It takes two parameters:

- `mIIN varchar(12)`, which is input string
- `mXMLOutput varchar(max)`, which is the result of execution

It works fine when I call it from Management Studio.

However, when I use the following code:

```
var iinParameter = new SqlParameter("@mIIN", SqlDbType.VarChar, 12) { Value = "123456123456" };
var outputParameter = new SqlParameter("@mXMLContent", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
_dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("GetInfo", iinParameter, outputParameter);
```

which results in the error

> Procedure or function 'GetInfo' expects parameter '@mIIN', which was not supplied

EF6 contains the following messages:

```
Started transaction at 15.12.2015 14:27:27 +06:00  
GetInfo  
-- @mIIN: '123456123456' (Type = AnsiString, IsNullable = false, Size = 12)   
-- @mXMLContent: '' (Type = AnsiString, Direction = Output, IsNullable = false, Size = -1)  
-- Executing at 15.12.2015 14:27:27 +06:00  
-- Failed in 2 ms with error: Procedure or function 'GetInfo' expects parameter '@mIIN', which was not supplied.
```

What can cause that problem? I am passing this parameter, why doesn't it accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
_dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec GetInfo @mIIN, @mXMLContent OUTPUT", iinParameter, outputParameter);
```

Comment: Nice one. It really does work, even without `exec` in the beginning. Why should I specify arguments this way? Doesn't it pass these arguments itself to the stored procedure?

Comment: Sadly not. It needs to marry up the parameter name in the SqlParameter with that in the command text.

Answer (score 0):

I think that problem is in your subprocedure.
Log message tells that parameter was suplied to `GetInfo`, and error is related to subprocedure `IBRC_GetClientInfo`. Check your procedure that parameter inside is properly passed.

Comment: Oh, I am really sorry for confusing you...I have just copied another call log. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things that are must to call a store procedure using EF6.

1. Provide all parameters including optional parameters.
2. Define parameter values as SqlParameter.
3. Provide all values as string in SqlParameter constructor.